# Maintain Leading Zeroes In An Integer Python

Tags: python, string, integer

I have some code that calculates a number as a string and uses

```
.zfill(N)
```

But its later converted to an int and the zero disappears. Is there any way to keep the leading zero(es)?

An example of this could be the following:

```
Input = input()
#Input has leading zeroes.
Input = int(Input)
#Leading zero disappears
#Later in the code
#Print_Text is a function that needs the leading zeroes
Print_Text(Input)
```

The leading zeroes are supposed to increase the length of the function to a multiple of 3

Comment: An integer can't have leading zero's

Comment: Integers don't have leading zeros. You need to keep it as a string.

Comment: Is there a way to convert it back to a string and add in leading zeroes later so that the length of the string is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: I have created an example

Comment: If the leading zeros are significant, then what you have is not an integer, it's a string. Don"t convert it to an `int`, keep it as the user entered it, as a string.

Comment: Why not keep the string and the `int()` of it in *separate* variables?

Comment: At the end I just realized that I just needed to add zeroes till the length was divisible by 3. So i converted it to a string and than used .zfill to add more zeroes just before the function.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to model this is to retain the original input `str`,
converting to `int` as needed.

Here is a hacky way to recover from mis-modeling:

```py
def with_zeros(x: int) -> str:
    n = len(str(x))
    while n % 3:
        n += 1
    assert n % 3 == 0

    return str(x).zfill(n)
```

Notice that we obtain a different number of `"0"` zeros for ±1 inputs.
Adjust to taste if that doesn't match your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just before the function I used

> .zfill()

To add enough zeroes to make it divisible by 3. If anyone wants the code is as follows:

```
EncodedString = EncodedString.zfill(len(EncodedString) + ((3 -len(EncodedString) % 3) % 3 or 3))
```